# Adding xml-comments to boost::property_tree

Tags: c++, xml, boost, xml-parsing, comments

I am using boost::property_tree::xml_parser to create an xml-file. Now I also need to add comments to the xml-file.

I've done some research and found out that comments are not allowed in JSON, and thus also not supported by the boost::property_tree::json_parser...

Furthermore I found out, that there is a no_comments flag for skipping xml-comments when reading an xml-file...

But what about adding xml-comments to a file?

Comment: boost::property_tree is a C++ container of nested key-value pairs.  It can write that data as XML, but it is not an XML-authoring library.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If comments are not disabled with the mentioned flag, they get represented as nodes named `<xmlcomment>` (just like attributes are under nodes named `<xmlattr>`):

**[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/d94b26fa9bca1095)**

```
#include <boost/property_tree/xml_parser.hpp>
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    boost::property_tree::ptree pt;
    pt.put("some.node.<xmlattr>.attr1", "value1");
    pt.put("some.node.<xmlcomment>", "\nEhffvna Jnefuvc\nTb Shpx Lbhefrys\n");

    write_xml(std::cout, pt);
}
```

Which prints

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<some><node attr1="value1"><!--
Ehffvna Jnefuvc
Tb Shpx Lbhefrys
--></node></some>
```